# Download Picture in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Dear all I am using below code to download the picture in android,
Where _in is as Input Stream and DataInputStream _din .
I use one URL to download the picture.but sometimes it returning me picture and sometimes it not showing null in bitmap.I have one question here, one is this good way to download picture  or suggestion what can be wrong in this picture that same code sometimes returning picture and sometimes it not working ?

```
if (_in == null) {
        _in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    }
    if (_din == null) {
        _din = new DataInputStream(_in);
    }

    byte[] data = new byte[0];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = _din.read(buffer)) > 0) {           
        byte[] newData = new byte[data.length + bytesRead];         
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, newData, 0, data.length);         
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, newData, data.length, bytesRead);           
        data = newData;
    }       
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me whether you problem still occurs.

```
Bitmap ret;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;          
        try
        {
            URL u = new URL(mUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            int httpCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (httpCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || httpCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED)
            {
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                ret = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            }
            else
            {
                ret = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ret = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a temp buffer for your image *InputStream*? Just use the UrlConnection InputStream directly with the BitmapFactory:

```
_in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(_in);
```

This should always work if your images are ok.

Comment: hi nice hint . . I did its working . . doing more testing to make it answer .  .